# problems lighting up LED on pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, led

HI i am new tp pi and python and wanted to create something that simply turns on and off a led.

It does not seem to work and not sure why?

here is the python script:

```
    from gpiozero import LED, Button

from time import sleep

led = LED(2)
led.on()


while True:
    range(100) and None
    led.on()
    sleep(0.5)
    led.off()
    sleep(0.5)
```

Here is a pic of my pi 3 wiring:

[image]

I followed this guide

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html

Comment: Have you tried turning your LED around, they will only work in one direction.

Comment: Awsome turning around the led fixed it!

Comment: @CoderMike Are you going to make that an answer to get credit for it? Otherwise someone else might run with the glory.

Comment: How do I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the line `range(100) and None` which is causing your loop to exit. You need to remove it. Where did it come from? It's not in the docs.

If you want to loop 100 times, change the `while True:` to `for i in range(100):`

Also it's probably just the way you pasted in the code here but your first line is indented, just make sure it isn't indented in your program.

Comment: HI. tried that and it did not work, the led light does not turn on. i added a print(i) to check if its hitting atht bit of the code and it does

Comment: "The problem is caused by the line `range(100) and None`" No, it isn't. That expression is well-formed so it's not throwing an exception to terminate the loop. It's not part of the `while` condition so its result does not control the `while`. It's also so trivial that its execution time should not be significantly affecting the rest of the loop operations. It is indeed pointless here, but it is certainly **not** the cause of the failure.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake.